# TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function

Tags: javascript

I'm getting this error type in my javascript. Can anyone tell me what is wrong here. I just started learning javascript.

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$('#myCarousel').oneCarousel({
                easeIn: 'rotateIn',
                interval: 5000,
                pause: 'hover'
            })')
```

Code:

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#myCarousel').oneCarousel({
                easeIn: 'rotateIn',
                interval: 5000,
                pause: 'hover'
            });
```

Comment: Hard to be sure without more but it looks like you're not importing jQuery.

Comment: @dystroy - if that were the case it would fail on `$(document)`

Comment: I'm in two minds as to whether this is a dup of your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14538674/javascript-error-typeerror-f-carousel-is-not-a-function) - to avoid appearances of cross-posting, it's worth hyperlinking to your previous question, explaining how it is different if necessary. However I don't think there is enough detail here to determine what the issue is. Can you add in links into your question for the oneCarousel plugin, and reference which version of jQuery you're using?

Comment: If this is the same problem as your other question, I offered some ideas in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

`$('#myCarousel').oneCarousel` is undefined.  You're probably missing whatever file defines `$.fn.oneCarousel`